# Aggregation in Excel

Tags: excel, aggregate

I want to excel to do the aggregation of data based on a reference column:
the data I have in the excel is as below:

```
COL-A   COL-B>
    A     1
    B     2
    C     3
    D     4
    A     2
    C     1
    E     5
    F     2
    B     3
```

AND

I need the final values to be aggregated on COl-A as:

```
COL-A  COLB
    A     3
    B     5
    C     4
    D     4
    E     5
    F     2
```

Could any please help how to acheive this in excel?

Answer (score 2):

use a pivot table. Give column headers to both Column A (eg: alphabet) and Column B (eg: value). Select both the columns including header. Go to insert->pivot table. In the pivot table options, give row header as alphabet and 'value' in Values field.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sandeep, the best dynamic solution is a **Pivot Table**.

Yet, if you wanted to use formula, you could use the `SUMIF` formula.

For instance, put in cell `C2` this kind of formula:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!A2:A10,A2,Sheet1!B2:B10)
```